# Postman check if response value is greater than or equal to another value

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I have a request in which a filter is added in the URL itself. Let the filter be named minAgeDecimal. In the response i should get listings with a variable AgeDecimal which is greater than or equal to the requested MinAgeDecimal value.
Sample MinAgeDecimal value=2.
Sample AgeDecimal value in response="AgeDecimal": "6.00".
I tried this code

```
pm.test("Check if AgeDecimal is more than the MinAgeDecimal filter ", function () {
    pm.expect(AgeDecimal).to.be.above(MinAgeDecimal);
});
```

But im getting an error: `Check if AgeDecimal is more than the MinAgeDecimal filter  | AssertionError: expected '6.00' to be a number or a date`.

Comment: Try `parseFloat()` to convert from string to number.

Comment: `var numberAgeDecimal = parseFloat(AgeDecimal)

pm.test("Check if AgeDecimal is more than the MinAgeDecimal filter ", function() {
    pm.expect(AgeDecimal).to.be.above(numberAgeDecimal);
   
});` Tried this but im still getting an error

Comment: Same error as before?

Comment: Yes the same error: AssertionError: expected '6.00' to be a number or a date

Comment: Try the `parseFloat()` also on `numberAgeDecimal`

Comment: Ok so i parsed both the variables. The previous error is fixed. But some cases are failing whenever these values are equal. How can change the condition from greater than to greater than or equal ?

Comment: Ok solved the issue. Just used the .to.be.at.least statement. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Could you please upvote those of my comments you found useful? Thanks.